# Get specific ACF key and value from all posts - no access to DB

Tags: wp-query, customization, query

I have a custom post type "product" and I want to retrieve and display on a page all the values for a ACF field "product_url". I don't have access to the db via PHP MyAdmin, so I'm trying to query the data and display on a page. I cannot get it to work correctly. The closest I have come is getting Post Titles, but anytime I modify the below code, it stops working.

```
function output_product_links() {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_post_type = 'product'; 
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID, post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s and post_status = 'publish'", $custom_post_type ), ARRAY_A );
    if ( ! $results )
            return;
            $output = '<ul id="links">';
            foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
            $output .= '<li id="' . $post['ID'] . '">' . $post['post_title'] . '</li>';
                }
            $output .= '</ul>';
            return $output;
    }
```

Whenever I change "post_title" in the SQL query and the $output to "product_url" nothing is output. I would like a list that displays the product name then the product url for all posts type=product in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using $wpdb? This is a simple query,
 check the ACF docs for usage examples (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)

```
<?php 
// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'product'
);

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ):?>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
        <li>
            <?php the_title();?> - <a href="<?php the_field('product_url');?>"><?php the_field('product_url');?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>

<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```